# Recovering lost or stolen phone using IMEI

Tags: data-recovery, lost-phone

I have lost my android phone please help me find its location. I have tried to recover it but all in vain.

What can I do to recover it back using 
IMEI ?

Answer (score 0):

Call your provider.  They have support teams whose entire purpose is to find lost phones.